# jQuery's data() function does not seem to be working right.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-3

Previously I had been doing:

My HTML:

```
<span id="foo" data-foo-bar="42">The Answer</span>
```

My "jquery":

```
const fooElement = $('#foo');
const fooBar = fooElement.data('foo-bar'); // 42
// or
const fBar = fooElement.data()['foo-bar']; // 42
```

But after I upgraded jquery (to 3.0) I get this:

```
const fooElement = $('#foo');
const fooBar = fooElement.data('foo-bar'); // undefined
// or
const fBar = fooElement.data()['foo-bar']; // undefined
```

How can I fix this?

What changed?

Comment: check here, https://plnkr.co/edit/0g9ITDAouWBL7XYRZzAO?p=preview seems to be working fine with jquery 3.0

Comment: @Deep That is odd as the object only contains fooBar: 42 plnkr.co/edit/eTxAPEXjUNi0b7RxUov7?p=preview . That must be something your browser is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What changed was that there is now a [breaking change: .data() names containing dashes](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-data-names-containing-dashes)

Which means that what you tried will **no longer work**!

What you can do is this:

```
const fooElement = $('#foo');
const fooBar = fooElement.data('fooBar'); // 42
// or
const fBar = fooElement.data()['fooBar']; // 42
```

This is because jquery now camelCases all "kebab-case" (jquery's word not mine) data attributes.

What you can use (if you want), is the actual data attribute:

```
const fooElement = document.getElementById('foo');
const fooBar = fooElement.getAttribute('data-foo-bar');  // 42
```

If you want to learn more about DOM attributes vs DOM properties you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/561731).